# Using @Username links

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With the rise of twitter, it has become now fairly commonplace to use the @Username format to reply to someone. I was wondering if there would be a way to have the system detect that use to 1) create a hyperlink to the mentioned person's profile page and 2) to create a notification (à la twitter) to the mentioned person (possibly on a dedicated page instead of via email).

Comment: (2) already works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, this already works. See:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

and

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/

The notation you're looking for is specific to comments, but broadly speaking, notifications will occur for

1. new answers to *your* questions
2. comments on *your* posts
3. comments which reply using `@username` notation to an earlier comment you left

Comment: Ah, neat I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if for example me and Jonas Meyer comment in a post and someone does @Jonas?

Comment: @jonast they would have to enter it as @jonast not @jonas

Comment: Why aren't notifications to multiple users within the same comment supported? This is a (nonexistent) "feature" that people use all the time on math.SE. (It would be handy if it and useful if it actually worked.)

Comment: Sometimes @usernames hyperlinks (it goes blue), sometimes it does not. When it does not, does it mean that the reply, did not work, will the person be notified that he or she was mentioned?